# How to pass query string parameter to ajax call from data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using ajax call for hit the API & i want to send an query parameter, How can i send query parameter with ajax call. Here is my code. Any help on this will be appreciated, Thanks.

```
    $("[id*=btnok]").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var obj = {};
    obj = $.trim($("[id*=nodays]").val());
    $.ajax({
        url: "/apilink",
        "data": {
                "api": "api",
                "params": "?userType=driver&type=true&count=" + obj 
            },
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            console.log(r)
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're sending a POST request any properties in the `data` object will be added to the body of the request. To force a value to be sent in the querystring you need to manually append it to the string you provide to the `url` property.

Also note that defining `obj` as an empty object is redundant as `$.trim()` always returns a string.

```
$("[id*=btnok]").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var obj = $.trim($("[id*=nodays]").val());

  $.ajax({
    url: "/apilink?params=" + obj,
    data: {
      api: "api",
    },
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (r) {
      console.log(r)
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: how can i pass this params
"data": {
                    "api": "api",
                    "params": "?userType=driver&type=true&count=" + obj 
                },

Answer (score 0):

As I see you make a post request so parameters are passed in `params` property in request body. But as an option you can add string params to your `/apilink`. Like that: `/apilink?param1=val1&param2=val2`

Comment: how can i pass this params "data": { "api": "api", "params": "?userType=driver&type=true&count=" + obj },